# Spring + Jasperreports + Unicode Characters are not visible in PDF

Tags: spring, jasper-reports

I have done almost all the different things mentioned ranging from Font Extension to jasperreports.properties file; but unable to find the solution. Please assist.

I am using Ireport designer to create a pdf which contains UTF8 encoding. The font used in all the fields is Arial Unicode MS (which is used in all the fields). The output PDF generated shows unicode charactes in the default previewer and PDF previewr for itext.

However, when I use Spring Application to display the page, I get blanks instead of Unicode characters. I have created jasperreports-fonts-arialuni.jar and included in my project classpath but somehow I am not able to get those unicode characters.

Can someone please assist?

Thanks,